# Write a program in C that prompts the user to enter two dates and then indicates which date comes earlier on the calender

Tags: c, date

My code is as follow:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int m1, m2, d1, d2, y1, y2;

    printf("enter first date (mm/dd/yy): ");
    scanf("%d/%d/%d", &m1, &d1, &y1);

    printf("enter second date (mm/dd/yy): ");
    scanf("%d/%d/%d", &m2, &d2, &y2);

    if (y1<y2)
        printf("%d/%d/%.2d is earlier than %d/%d/%.2d\n",m1, d1, y1, m2, d2, y2);
    else
        printf("%d/%d/%.2d is earlier than %d/%d/%.2d\n",m2, d2, y2, m1, d1, y1);

    if (y1==y2)
    {if (m1<m2)
            printf("%d/%d/%.2d is earlier than %d/%d/%.2d\n",m1, d1, y1, m2, d2, y2);
    else if (m2<m1)
        printf("%d/%d/%.2d is earlier than %d/%d/%.2d\n",m2, d2, y2, m1, d1, y1);}

    if (y1==y2 && m1==m2)
    {if (d1<d2)
        printf("%d/%d/%.2d is earlier than %d/%d/%.2d\n",m1, d1, y1, m2, d2, y2);
    else
        printf("%d/%d/%.2d is earlier than %d/%d/%.2d\n",m2, d2, y2, m1, d1, y1);}

    return 0;

}
```

Im trying to keep it simple since I am a beginner and am only on chapter 5 in King's C Programming Modern Approach Textbook. When I enter the following:

enter first date (mm/dd/yy): 03/31/93
enter second date (mm/dd/yy): 04/31/93

the response i get is:

4/31/93 is earlier than 3/31/93 AND
3/31/93 is earlier than 4/31/93

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Change "mm/dd/yy" to "yy/mm/dd" and use ``strcmp()``.

Comment: In future, please, use the debugger (step-by-step debugging). This problem can be trivially debugged.

Comment: the code should be checking the returned value from the scanf calls to assure that all input operations were successful.. This code assumes that the year, month, day are valid values.  This is not a good assumption for several reasons.  Amongst other things each month has a specific number of days, except leap years, where February has an extra day, month is limited to 1...12, which may or may not have a leading 0, year is limited to 00...99, which may of may not have a leading 0.  Be careful of leading 0's as scanf will interpret them as octal numbers.

Answer (score 4):

Once you have found out that the year of the first date is less than the year of the second you should print an answer and return to prevent subsequent checks and result outputs, i.e.:

```
if (y1<y2) {
    printf("%d/%d/%.2d is earlier than %d/%d/%.2d\n",m1, d1, y1, m2, d2, y2);
    return 0;
}
```

Same applies to the month and the day field.

Comment: Do you realize that your answer does not fix the OP's problem?

Comment: @FreeNickname I don't know what problem do you mean, but as I've understood the problem is that the program produces two outputs when it should produce only one. What's the real problem?

Comment: Well, to be precise, your answer fixes that, you're right. But it introduces another problem: now if the second date is later than the first date, but years are equal, the result is incorrect. [ideone demo](http://ideone.com/gIKWX6). Your solution gets rid of the second output (the correct one), when you should get rid of the first.

Comment: I didn't offer the solution. This task is not even a problem that requires "solution", this is ridiculous IMO for such a simple task. If the author wants a thorough analysis of problems in the program and asks to write a complete robust program, then yes, my answer is not the solution. I simply pointed to the main mistake. By the way, I wonder why this question is even so popular at all to compete in solutions to it.

Comment: Well, the OP's problem was that the printed result was incorrect. In your case it is still incorrect.

Comment: As for the complete source, it's not required, of course. I just had nothing to do at the moment, and it didn't take much time, so I wrote it)

Answer (score 3):

In your first `if`'s `else` block you don't check whether `y1` is `>` than `y2`. That's why when they are equal (like in your case) `y1 > y2` is false, you enter the `else` block and the first (incorrect) reply is printed.

One possible solution is to replace `else` with `else if` (like you did for month):

```
if (y1 < y2) {
    printf("%d/%d/%.2d is earlier than %d/%d/%.2d\n",m1, d1, y1, m2, d2, y2);
}
else if (y2 < y1) {
    printf("%d/%d/%.2d is earlier than %d/%d/%.2d\n",m2, d2, y2, m1, d1, y1);
}
```

When we fix that, the next problem is that if you enter two exactly the same dates, your code will output that the second one is earlier for the same reason as before: `if (d1 < d2)` will return `false`, and you will get to the `else` block.
To fix that you could also use an `else if`:

```
if (y1 == y2 && m1 == m2) {
    if (d1 < d2) {
        printf("%d/%d/%.2d is earlier than %d/%d/%.2d\n",m1, d1, y1, m2, d2, y2);
    }
    else {
        if (d2 < d1) {
            printf("%d/%d/%.2d is earlier than %d/%d/%.2d\n",m2, d2, y2, m1, d1, y1);
        }
        else {
            printf("Dates are equal\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Also, to reduce code duplication, I would suggest to remember the result somehow, and then `printf` if only once in the end.

For instance, like so (one possible way):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define FIRST_DATE_IS_BIGGER (1)
#define SECOND_DATE_IS_BIGGER (-1)
#define DATES_ARE_EQUAL 0

int main(void)
{
    int m1, m2, d1, d2, y1, y2;
    int result = DATES_ARE_EQUAL;

    printf("Enter the first date (mm/dd/yy): ");
    scanf("%d/%d/%d", &m1, &d1, &y1);

    printf("Enter the second date (mm/dd/yy): ");
    scanf("%d/%d/%d", &m2, &d2, &y2);

    if (y1 < y2) {
        result = SECOND_DATE_IS_BIGGER;
    }
    else if (y2 < y1) {
        result = FIRST_DATE_IS_BIGGER;
    }
    else {
        if (m1 < m2) {
            result = SECOND_DATE_IS_BIGGER;
        }
        else if (m2 < m1) {
            result = FIRST_DATE_IS_BIGGER;
        }
        else {
            if (d1 < d2) {
                result = SECOND_DATE_IS_BIGGER;
            }
            else if (d2 < d1) {
                result = FIRST_DATE_IS_BIGGER;
            }
        }
    }

    switch (result) {
        case FIRST_DATE_IS_BIGGER:
            printf("%d/%d/%.2d is earlier than %d/%d/%.2d\n",m2, d2, y2, m1, d1, y1);
            break;
        case SECOND_DATE_IS_BIGGER:
            printf("%d/%d/%.2d is earlier than %d/%d/%.2d\n",m1, d1, y1, m2, d2, y2);
            break;
        case DATES_ARE_EQUAL:
            printf("Dates are equal.\n");
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[Ideone demo.](http://ideone.com/5zcP3v)

Comment: This is nicely extensible when user wants to add hours, minutes, seconds.